# App using NDK (native code) falls. How can i find out why?

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk, native-code, android-ndk-r4

My app is using NDK (4r-crystax in my case) to proccess images from a camera. Problem is, it falls after few minutes of work. I guess there can be some memory leaks or something like that, but i dont know how to find out where the problem is. This is a log around this error:

```
04-14 23:07:37.133: INFO/NATIVE CODE(14895): Detection percentage counted.
04-14 23:07:37.163: DEBUG/MDDetectorView(14895): Some debug info
04-14 23:07:37.193: DEBUG/dalvikvm(14895): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 19 objects / 872 bytes in 27ms
04-14 23:07:37.283: INFO/NATIVE CODE(14895): Image to proccess loaded.
04-14 23:07:37.493: INFO/ActivityManager(92): Process com.motiondetector (pid 14895) has died.
04-14 23:07:37.493: DEBUG/CameraService(67): Client::~Client E (pid 67, client 0xad08)
04-14 23:07:37.503: INFO/WindowManager(92): WIN DEATH: Window{46590698 com.motiondetector/com.motiondetector.MDMenuActivity paused=false}
04-14 23:07:37.513: ERROR/CameraService(67): getClientFromCookie: client appears to have died
```

Any ideas? Are there any usefull tools to help me find answer?

Is possible that Android kill on screen activity during proccessing a native code?

Comment: Have you tried using gdb? The ndk supports it, although it's not terribly straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using NDK r5 or greater, you can use the `ndk-gdb` script to run your program and connect to it via GDB. If your native code is crashing, it should drop you into the GDB command line, where you can examine the area of code that's causing the problem.